# NDSolve in exact points - nonlinear equation (Degrees and Radians confusion)

Tags: differential-equations

I found solutions of two nonlinear equations, but I have three small questions.

First I am in confusion because of initial value. The system is mechanical and unknown ϕ is an angle, which I set to be in position of 90 degrees (Pi/2). Is it correct setting in equation initial position?

Second question: I am looking for discrete points of an angle values here

```
 ϕ = 90 Degree (Pi/2 Radians)
 ϕ = 80 Degree (1.396 Radians)
 ϕ = 70 Degree (1.221 Radians)
 ϕ = 30 Degree (0.523 Radians)
 ϕ = 20 Degree (0.349 Radians)
 ϕ = 10 Degree (0.174 Radians)
 ϕ = 0 Degree (0 Radians)
```

Numerical solutions of these values down and in which time

```
 {z[t], z'[t], ϕ'[t], ϕ''[t], z''[t], t}
```

I solved the system and obtained solutions, but I don't know how to extract these values from the diagrams.

Third question: I am looking for to obtain FindMinimum[zsol[t],t] and FindMaximum[zsol[t],t] but Mathematica gives value which is not extrema because I can see from the diagram that it is not extrema.

```
 c1 = 7.5*10^3;
 m = 10;
 l = 1;
 M = 75;
 g = 9.81;

 {zsol, ϕsol} = 
   NDSolveValue[
     {z''[t] - (M l)/(m + M) ϕ''[t] Sin[ϕ[t]] - (M l)/(m + M) 
       (ϕ'[t])^2 Cos[ϕ[t]] + c1/(m + M) z[t] == 0, 
      ϕ''[t] - 1/l z''[t] Sin[ϕ[t]] + g/l Sin[ϕ[t]] == 0, 
      z[0] == -((M g)/c1), z'[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == Pi /2, ϕ'[0] == 0},
     {ϕ, z}, {t, 0, 15}]

 Plot[{zsol[t], ϕsol[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
 Plot[{zsol[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]
 Plot[{ϕsol[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}]
```

Solutions

[image]

Comment: small note i believe you've reversed `{zsol, ϕsol}` compared to the order you requested them.

Comment: take a look at the answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44334/findroot-constrained-to-maximum/44340#44340 using `WhenEvent`

Comment: As your interpolating functions are only valid in the t-range  where you solved the equation you should include that as a constraint. I would also suggest to use `NMinimize`/`NMaximize` if you search a global min/max of a numeric function, they seem to work well for your problem:`NMaximize[{zsol[t], 0 <= t <= 15}, t]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is correct.

Second

```
p1 = Plot[{zsol[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotPoints -> 500];
error = 0.01;
select[ϕ_] := 
 Select[First@Cases[p1, Line[x_] -> x, Infinity], Abs[#[[2]] - ϕ] < error &]
select[0.174]
Show[p1, ListPlot[%, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]]
```

If you need more precision，increase PlotPoints and decrease error.

The enhanced version

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ϕpos = {0, 0.174, 0.349, 0.523, 1.221, 1.396, 1.571};
c1 = 7.5*10^3; m = 10; l = 1; M = 75; g = 9.81;
sol = First@
   NDSolve[{z''[t] - (M l)/(m + M) ϕ''[
     t] Sin[ϕ[t]] - (M l)/(m + M) (ϕ'[t])^2 Cos[ϕ[t]] + c1/(m + M) z[t] == 
 0, ϕ''[t] - 1/l z''[t] Sin[ϕ[t]] + g/l Sin[ϕ[t]] == 0, z[0] == -((M g)/c1), 
 z'[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == Pi/2, ϕ'[0] == 0}, {ϕ, z}, {t,0, 15}];
error = 0.005; step = 0.002;
tpos[ϕ0_] := 
 Mean /@ Gather[Select[{#, ϕ[#] /. sol} & /@ Range[0, 5, step], 
 Abs[#[[2]] - ϕ0] < error &][[All, 1]], Abs[#1 - #2] < error &]
AllData[tlist_] := Table[{t, ϕ[t], z[t], z'[t], ϕ'[t], ϕ''[t], z''[t]}
 /. sol, {t, tlist}]
grid[ϕ_] := 
Grid@Join[{{"t", "ϕ", "z", "z'", "ϕ'", "ϕ''", "z''"}},AllData[tpos[ϕ]]]
trans[func_] := 
 Which[func == "ϕ", {1, 2}, func == "z", {1, 3}, 
  func == "z'", {1, 4}, func == "ϕ'", {1, 5}, 
  func == "ϕ''", {1, 6}, func == "z''", {1, 7}]
Manipulate[
 Column[{grid[ϕ], Show[Plot[Evaluate[ToExpression[func][t] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, 
 ImageSize -> 400], ListPlot[AllData[tpos[ϕ]][[All, trans[func]]], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]]}], {ϕ, ϕpos}, {func, {"ϕ", 
"z", "z'", "ϕ'", "ϕ''", "z''"}}, ControlType -> RadioButton]

zsol[t_] := z[t] /. sol;
max = {#2[[1, 2]], #1} & @@ NMaximize[{zsol[t], 0 < t < 5}, t]
min = {#2[[1, 2]], #1} & @@ NMinimize[{zsol[t], 0 < t < 5}, t]
Show[Plot[zsol[t], {t, 0, 5}], ListPlot[{max, min}, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I need position of z, velocity z', angular velocity ϕ' and angular acceleration ϕ'' for various ϕ which I choose and for which t. It should be table of 6x7 of data? {z[t], z'[t], ϕ'[t], ϕ''[t], z''[t], t}

Comment: just for first cycle

Comment: you need learn my code and rewrite it for you need.

Comment: I think I can handle, thank you very much

Comment: I used FindMaximum[zsol[t], t] on the segment but doesn't work? I obtained value which is not maximum because I can see from the diagram

Comment: @Pipe you shouldn't bury a new question in a comment. Edit the question to say you also want the max. (or post a new question)

Comment: so professional code