# Numerically Integrating to find a Maximum using NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically find an equilibrium (maximum) of a function using its differential. The following is a simplified version.

```
myEquilibrium[p_]:=Last[{myPreviousStep=1;NDSolve[{s'[t]==p-s[t],s[0]==myPreviousStep,WhenEvent[s[t]-myPreviousStep<10^-4||s[t]<10^-4,"StopIntegration"]},{s},{t,0,Infinity},StepMonitor:>(myPreviousStep=s[t])];myPreviousStep}]
```

myEquilibrium[.5] // 0.5 which is correct

The function should be constrained to positive s, which is why I included the `s[t]<10^-4` requirement. However this does not seem to work.

myEquilibrium[-.5] // -0.5 but should be 10^-4

The NDSolve should also not go to `0` exactly, as the real, non-simplified version contains a `1/s[t]` in the differential. That's another reason I want the procedure to stop at `s[t]=10^-4`, before `s[t]=0`.

myEquilibrium[0] // 0. but should be 10^-4

Finally, I often get `NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 6.57563031118913721074693815431*^4952. >>` and `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 1.79769313486*^308, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>`. What would typically solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `s[t]` is decreasing whenever `p < 1`, `s[t] - myPreviousStep < 10^-4` will always be `True`.  `WhenEvent[cond, action]` evaluates `action` when the condition **changes** from `False` to `True`; however, the condition is always `True` when `p < 1`.  You need something like `Abs[s[t] - myPreviousStep] < 10^-4`, instead.  Note that if `p` is closer to `1` than `10^-4`, then the same thing happens. Also note this condition controls the accuracy in an indirect way, dependent on the convergence rate of `NDSolve` on your particular ODE.)

```
myEquilibrium[p_] := 
 Last[{myPreviousStep = 1; 
   NDSolve[{s'[t] == p - s[t], s[0] == myPreviousStep,
      WhenEvent[s[t] < 10^-4 || Abs[s[t] - myPreviousStep] < 10^-4, 
       "StopIntegration"]}, {s}, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
     StepMonitor :> (myPreviousStep = s[t])]; myPreviousStep}]
```

If you want to handle initial values `p` that happen to land close to an equilibrium position, then the following forces the condition to be `False` on the second step.  The function `step` redefines itself after the first step.  The first definition forces the condition `Abs[s[t] - myPreviousStep] < 10^-4` to be `False`.

```
SetAttributes[step, HoldFirst];
myEquilibrium[p_] := Last[{
   step[var_, s_] := (var = s + 2. 10^-4; 
     step[var2_, s2_] := var2 = s2;); myPreviousStep = 1; 
   NDSolve[{s'[t] == p - s[t], s[0] == myPreviousStep,
     WhenEvent[s[t] < 10^-4 || Abs[s[t] - myPreviousStep] < 10^-4, 
      "StopIntegration"]}, {s}, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
    StepMonitor :> step[myPreviousStep, s[t]]]; myPreviousStep}]
```

Comment: Thanks again Michael. The Abs I just forgot to add, but it makes all the difference. If I understand correctly, the second part of your answer explain how to change the order in which Mathematica 'updates' values, such that certain conditions are met one step earlier than otherwise. Is that correct?

Comment: Seems to work very well for the full version too. I still get 'NDSolve::evcvmit: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations between t = 51.8086163110953 and t = 53.5515089038894. >>' for a short range of values of the parameters.

Comment: @LBogaardt The second method works on `myEquilibrium[1 - 0.00001]`, which may not be important in your use-case.  At the first step taken by `NDSolve`, the `step` function gives `myPreviousStep` a bogus value  constructed to make the `WhenEvent` condition be `False`.  On subsequent steps, it is equivalent to `myPreviousStep = s[t]`.  It ensures that the condition in `WhenEvent` is `False` for at least one step taken by `NDSolve`.  It's an ad hoc solution, which may not be bulletproof in general although it seems like it would work for equilibria where `s'[t]` is proportional to `p - s[t]`.

Comment: @LBogaardt `NDSolve::evcvmit` can happen if the coefficient of `p - s[t]` is very small or `p - s[t]` is raised to a high power.  For example, `s'[t] == 10^-6 (p - s[t])` or `s'[t] == (p - s[t])^3`.  There are probably other types of difficulties, too.  `WhenEvent` has a `"LocationMethod"` option, which might be of interest.